# How to use EE classes like DB,channel API from a php file

Tags: php, database, channel-entries-api

I have a requirement in one of my EE site wherein I need to insert some data in tables and make some channel entries using EE channel API,I am able to do this within a EE template using database class or channel API..like

```
 $this->EE->db->insert("INSERT QUERY");
```

But I have to do the same thing from a Php file which is located at root (same level of index.php file). Can anyone please help me out here.

I want to know what files to be included and what classes to be initiated or anything to be able to use EE object ($this->EE) within in a php file (located at root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out Rob Sanchez' EE Bootstrap: https://github.com/rsanchez/ExpressionEngine-Bootstrap

It does just what you're looking for. I've used it myself for some projects where I didn't want to put code inside an EE add-on.

Comment: Thanks for the your reply....and sorry for my late reply :)